# Magento en PHP: Show a different widget each day and loop at the end

Tags: php, magento

In my Magento webshop i would like to show different widgets each day.

I have 10 different widgets for 10 different days.
After the 10 days the first widget should be shown again.

This code will be part in a phtml from.

What i want:

Show on day 1:

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="1"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

Show on day 2:

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="2"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

Show on day 3:

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="3"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

....

Show on day 10:

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="10"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

And after day 10 restart with day 1.
This without an end date ...

How can i do this?

**UPDATE 17-04-2015:**
In my example the block_id are in sequence. But probably the won't be upfollowing block_id's ...
So Day 1 could have `block_id="12"`, day 2: `block_id="4"`, day 3: `block_id="21"` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date and modulus to get a value 1-10.

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="'.((date('z')%10)+1).'"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

To explain the parts...

```
date('z'); //the day of the year will be an integer 1-365
%10  //modulus is the remainder after division, so as the number climbs it will go 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3....
+1 //turns your 0-9 values into 1-10 to match block ids.
```

And the updated question now asks...what if my block ids aren't sequential?  I think in that case you can define an array with keys 1-10 and values for your actual block ids.

```
$idMapping = array(
    1    => 3,
    2  => 5,
    3  => 9,
    4 => 13,
    5 => 17,
    6 => 23,
    7 => 29,
    8 => 31,
    9 => 37,
    10 => 41
);
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="myextension/widget_block" block_id="'.$idMapping[(date('z')%10)+1].'"}}');
echo $_widget;
```

One other thing about my solution.  The number of days in the year is not divisible by 10, so at the end of the year when it goes from 365 back to 1 you won't get a full rotation through all 10 deals.  So the fix for that would be to generate our daily incremented value by comparing it to a fixed date, so it will just always climb as you move further away from that date.

```
$date = "2015-04-17";
$diff = abs(strtotime($date) - time());
$days = floor($diff/3600/24); //converts seconds to hours, then to days
//so now you can replace date('z') with $days and you'll loop continuously without any weird gap at the end of the year.
```

Comment: In my question I used following block Numbers. Which is The most optimal situation. But it could happen that they vary and are not as Nice following up. How can that be solved?